# Return a "one" for the first instance of duplicate values and a "zero" for the other instances

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, duplicate

I'm trying to write a formula to check for duplicates in one column.

It should return a `1` for the first instance of the duplicates and a `0` for the other instances. If the value doesn't have a duplicate it should return a `1` as well.

I tried to use

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B:$B, B6)>1,1,0)
```

but it returns a `1` for the other instances of the duplicates.

Any ideas?

Comment: could you please show the sample data inducing the effect of the command you have used.

Comment: You mean to say that you want to count only first instance Of Items With Formula and return 1 & for second instance it should O , write ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Write this formula is Cell C1 and fill down:

```
=(COUNTIF($B$1:$B1,$B1)=1)+0
```

**How it works:**

- The Formula finds all the first instance of values, and then counts
  them to put 1 then put 0 for others.

**N.B.**

- Check the Screen Shot the Formula is finding duplicates in the column B and 
  returns 1 for the first instance but 0 for the other instances.

Answer (score 4):

That is close. Your formula counts if a value occurs more than once in the entire column for every occurrence of the value. In other words, it flags all the duplicate values with a one everywhere, and flags single values with a zero.

You need a formula that only checks the *previous* values:

```dart
=IF(COUNTIF($B$1:$B6, B6)>1,0,1)
```

Note that the `$B$1` contains absolute column and row references, whilst `$B6` contains a relative row reference.

The end result is that the formula only counts the cells in the `B` column from the current cell up to the top. If the count is more than one, then the current `B` cell must contain the second or later instance of a duplicate.

Comment: I guess your formula should be written in Row 6 and pulled upside?